# Javascript Bit Manipulaton Issue

Tags: javascript, bit-manipulation

I was playing with JavaScript's bit manipulation where i tried "and operation" with various numbers and every time got binary result but for few numbers i am always getting weird decimal number.

```
10100 & 1000 = 864
```

864 why?

Comment: `&&` is logical operator, `&` is bitwise operator

Comment: 10100 and 1000 are decimal. To force treating them as binary you need to use binary prefix like `0b10100 & 0b1000`

Comment: Thanks... 0b would yield right result.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [What does this symbol mean in JavaScript?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9549780/what-does-this-symbol-mean-in-javascript)

Answer (score 2):

`&&` is logical operator, `&` is bitwise logical operator

```
decimal | binary
 ------------------------
  10100 = 10011101110100
   1000 =     1111101000
        &
    864 =     1101100000
```

As @Andrey mention, if you want to force binary notation use `0b` prefix
`0b10100` and `0b1000`